# Is a big code embedded into the first frame of root on Flash considered a bad practice?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am planning to create a game with the help of Flash CS3/AS3. This game will feature too many functions and lots of code. A 30-seconds demo alone I've been making here already has 5,000 lines of code, and will only get bigger and bigger as I make progress.

I'm planning on separating snippets of this code into separate as files, so I can embed them on the timeline using the include function, but before I proceed, I need to know: Is this considered a bad practice?

I mean, there will be a point in development where the code will become so huge, it might threaten the game's stability, or am I just paranoid and this is a perfectly normal way to address this issue. Pasting all the important functionality on the timeline and being done with it?

Comment: any code embedded in any frame is bad practice. I also have the feeling that 30 second demo for 5000 lines of code only means bad coding skills.

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionScript code isn't going to affect your load time nearly as much as your assets. Any audio assets have to be embedded in your actionscript compile frame, which you can pick from your document properties.

If you're using library assets that are connected to AS Classes, the only place you can really practically defer loading is visual assets that are placed on stage later in the timeline, by not checking "compile on frame X" (whatever frame you selected as your compile frame). Timeline scripts are, as a rule, bad practice, so I assume that you're not using them.

include is also bad practice. I suspect it won't work like you want, but it also breaks compile-time error checking pretty hard.

I can't imagine needing 5000 lines of code for a demo that size, so you may want to revisit your design. Look for places you can reuse code (literally reuse the same code, not copy and paste it).

Answer (score -1):

That's depend a lot if you are using OOP to develop or if you type your whole code in a procedural way. Having some codes drop on separate movieclip/sprite is not a bad thing, I even feel it's good! but that's true if each of them manage themself without depending. For example in a video game if you want to manage with script the animation of a specific monster, that's a great way to write the code inside his movieclip and make sure that his own script doesn't depend on others script.

Comment: By definition putting code in frame is procedural so it does not depend as you say.

Comment: If the code only manage the animation of a movieclip and that code doesn't depend on others part of the main project code, I feel it's a perfect way to manage... That's even more easy to update because you don't need to read the whole main code each time you want to update the movieclip animation script, you open the movieclip itself and edit his own code. If the structure is correctly prepare, in the case you delete this movieclip, it doesn't display any alert. A main OOP structure mixed with X movieclips using key's labels, stop(), gotoandplay, gotoandstop(), etc. is very efficient.

Comment: it's really not efficient at all. It can feel that way if you have only a few mc to deal with but quickly when you start dealing with a couple dozen or more this becomes a maintenance nightmare. You do 100% OOP or you don't, if you don't asking about good/bad practice is really irrelevant cos you are only doing bad.

Comment: That's only depend on what @user3052587 wants at the end, if he wants to create something very general, each movieclip react in a similar way or if he wants to get a more "traditional" result with a huge amount of movieclips all reacting in a different way but that he didn't say.